# EXCEL to CSV (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export-to-csv

I need to export a Excel sheet to cdv (easy) but I need to have this format for numbers:

102.682,35

and my csv file is doing this:
3928.5400000000027

I need to have thousands quote separator.

any idea?

Comment: Does the value in a cell already have the desired format?

Comment: Yes, but it is numeric so when I save it to csv, I did not have any thousand separator anymore.

Comment: Erm…  You are aware that "CSV" stands for "Comma Separated Values", aren't you?  As in `102.682,35` would become 2 fields, `102.682` and `35`...  For this reason, saving as CSV from Excel removes the Thousands separator from numbers, and change the Decimal separator to a `.` - if you want it in your desired format, then you would need to change it from Numeric data into a Text String

Comment: Yes I know that, but this is for my head office and their format is like this:Cash at Bank; 102.682,35   ;;;;

Comment: Just loop the rows and create the CSV. As you're looping you can use logic to format the string. Commas are ok in CSV fields. That's why qualifiers exist. Do you need sample code?

Comment: yes please could you provide sample code

Comment: I feel bad because all I have is C# code. I thought I had a VB version already. If I give you that can you translate? It's not too much to convert to VBA. In essence,  you're grabbing the entire range you want into an object array via VBA and then looping that array to create comma separated text rows. You'll want to check each field of each row for a comma and if it contains one you need to wrap in double quotes. You'd also be checking if something is a number and reformatting it respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Two things here. If the CSV will be imported back into an Excel spreadsheet, then having a comma as a thousands separator is a *visual format* issue. This means that it can be formatted to show the thousands comma once it's back in Excel. In this case, don't worry about adding a thousands comma to the CSV file, just make sure to format the cells later.

Secondly, if you really do need a thousands comma in the CSV file you can do this yourself with VBA by learning how to create a loop over your data range and write to a text file in the CSV format. Now the thing about CSV is that the "separator" doesn't have to be a "comma" (even though CSV means "comma separated values"). You can choose any character that won't be used within any value.

Typically you'd do this if a comma is likely to appear in a value such as a string:

```
 This is a sentence, but it has a comma embedded within it.
```

In your case you want a comma in a number value `133,491.234`. So for the separator in a CSV file, choose another character such as the vertical pipe `|`. Now the values in the CSV file would look like this:

```
Doctor|Smith, John|$142,533|Brown Eyes
```

Look at this website to learn to [Write Data to Text File](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/write-data-to-text-file.html) and when you're looping over the cell values and come to the value that needs the thousands comma, use the `Format` function similar to this:

```
Format(cellValue, "#,##0.00")
```